# CSS selector vs Class for styling elements

Tags: html, css, coding-style

Let us look at below HTML chunk,
    [image: HTML Chunk]

Here, in the above chunk, we are using class for each div.
We can also replace `classes` with `CSS selectors`

```
     .first{
      /*  some styles  */
      }
      .first:nth-child(1){
      /*  some styles  */
      }
      .first div:nth-child(1){
      /*  some styles  */
      }
```

The above CSS chunk can also satisfies our requirement
What is the best practice? Explain the conditions where we can use `selectors` and `classes`
thanks :)

Comment: The first advantage that comes to mind for using classes is that you have to refactor all subsequent `:nth-child()` selectors when you insert a new element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's better to use CSS selectors style when the style is related to the position of elements and otherwise use classes.

For example, if a table's background of each line is related to their position, say, red for the first line, green for the second line, blue for the third line, red for the fourth line, and green for the sixth line and so on. It's better to use CSS selectors like `:nth-child(3n+1)` in this case so that you don't need to write the extra information like `class='red'` in HTML which is a bad practice since it's hard to change if you want to use four colors later.

But if the background of the table lines are decided by their values, say, red for values less than 0, green for values greater than 0, and blue for 0. You may find it quite hard to express this in CSS selectors so adding `class='lz0'` may be a wise thing to do.

In conclusion, bear it in mind that content and style should be decoupled. Use HTML for content and structure and use CSS for style.